# EasyE4 send data to database

Tags: pcb, ethernet

I am trying to use an EasyE4 (from Eaton) to measure several sensors in my stable. It needs to send a value to the database when it measures something from a sensor. How can I do this? Can i send this directly to a database or do i have to use a PHP script with a GET or POST, or does this not work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be strictly a software question, not specific to electrical engineering.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson How about vote for migration instead.  That would be more useful to the user.

Comment: @Aaron I don't know to where the question should be migrated. There may not be an appropriate SE site. In any event, it is really the OP's responsibility to find an appropriate site for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Electrical Engineering stack exchange. It's usually helpful to put a link to the device you are asking about.

From the Eaton website:

> The JSON API of the easyE4 web server can be used to communicate via
>   **HTTP-GET requests**. This means that operands, device settings and
>   easyE4 data can be accessed in writing and reading mode in different
>   programming environments.

So this means you'd need to have a server side program that pulls JSON data from the easyE4 and then stuff that data into the database.

There are many architectures that can solve this.  One example would be, the program can live on the same server as the DB and then you don't need to have a remote connection to the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Do you have any idea how i can do this using a php file with $_GET? I am looking at the documentation but it's hard to find anything good.

Comment: @CasDE-IT That's a question for https://stackoverflow.com/  But having gone down that road before, I'd recommend against making a stand alone daemon from PHP.  It's cumbersome to debug. If you are using PHP as the back end to a web page that will then do what you are asking, that's fine.

Comment: This should have been and will likely be migrated to https://stackoverflow.com. Any votes here will also be migrated to stackoverflow.